# How to connect Service bus queue to Azure Data Factory as source?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-data-factory

I have a service bus configured where i get messages in my subscription, I would like to move the data from the messages in the service bus queue to table storage using Azure Data factory, I would like to know if it is possible to do it.i couldn't find any online resource which talks about service bus as a source so would like to know if anyone has any experience here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got from Microsoft, so posting it here for community>

> Data Factory does not have a connector for Service bus. However there
> are several options available to you.
>
> You can create a consumer for Data Factory to call upon.
>
> You can raise a feature request in the feedback forum.
>
> You could re-route your messages to be written to blob, and then
> leverage the Blob Event Trigger.
>
> Use ADF Web Activity to retrieve a message.
>
> By "create a consumer for Data Factory to call upon," I mean either
> create a Function App which batch-reads the messages, and returns
> them, utilizing ADF Azure Function, or , create some code to do the
> same with the ADF Batch Service Custom Activity. There are more
> variations as well.
>
> Which one to use, depends upon your volume and cadence (frequency).